# How To Find The Rate At Which User Watches a Video Then Goes To Another Webpage (CTR)

Tags: google-analytics

Can someone tell me what's the best way to measure users that go to a home page and watch a video then go to another page in the same website vs a user that goes to the website and doesn't watch the video.  I would like to provide a measurement showing users that watched the video then went somewhere else in the same website vs users that didn't watch the video.  I am thinking that users that watch a video would go to another webpage at a higher rate then users that don't watch the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequence segments are your friend! They allow you to create a segment based on Users or Sessions performing actions on your site in a particular order.

Are you tracking video plays via event tracking?

If so, you could create a sequence segment based on sessions, where the sequence starts anywhere in the session, with step 1 based on the event, and step 2 immediately follows as a pageview of any page on the site excluding the home page (so as to not include possible home page refreshes).

This would give more granular data than (for example) a sequence segment including someone simply visiting the homepage and then navigating to another page, without actually having watched any of the video.
[image]

Couple of good articles on Sequence Segments that are worth the read:
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/04/04/sequence-segments-more-accurate-reporting/
https://online-metrics.com/how-to-leverage-sequence-based-segments-in-google-analytics/